# Replacing words in shell command

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm a bit new at this so bear with me. I would like to replace certain text that is attached to a variable? or is it string? i can't remember what the dickens it's called.

> delete me /from/this/here/string/

```
var="delete me /from/this\ here\ string/"
```

i tried:

```
echo $var | sed 's/^\(.* \)\(delete\sthis \)$/\wtf?\1/g'
echo $var | sed 's/.*\//delete this;/g'
awk ${var/123/abc};
```

I would like to git riddens of the 'delete me' printing. the second part always changes, but 'delete me' is always present. i'm too old for this, so thank you

Comment: hello? is anyone there?

Comment: oh dear, i need to go lay down

Comment: no need to "ping" people after 2 hours; answers can take days to show up on [so].

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
> var="delete me /from/this\ here\ string/"
> echo "${var/delete me/}"
 /from/this\ here\ string/
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
echo $var|sed 's/\(^[^/]*\)/abc/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var="delete me /from/this\ here\ string/"

var="$(printf '%s' "$var" | sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*delete[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*//' -e 's/\\//g')"

echo "$var"
```

My output:

```
/from/this here string/
```

It simply substitutes the word "delete" and a word following it, removing all space before and after the phrase of course. This allows it to work on "delete me", "delete this", and even "\t \t delete \t \t \t me_too \t \t \t" because a "blank" is a space or a tab character (\t). It will only work for two words starting with "delete" at the beginning.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for this, i'm getting `/from/this\ here\ string/`, i wonder why it's not the same. you nipped the first part which is what i couldn't figure on doing

Comment: is there an advantage of using sed over awk?

Comment: You could use awk, but sed is made for such tasks as these. The name sed comes from "stream editor" or something like that; it does its job as a simple editor. Awk is a record processor. If you have columns of data in files, awk is great for that.

Comment: I just edited the answer to remove the `\\` characters. I didn't realize they were literal backslashes.